# Unable to pass object to angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs

This may be common out here, but I can't find the solution. I am trying to pass params to an angular directive, as objects, but I only get 'undefined'.

Directive:

```
app.directive('someInfo', ['someService', function (someService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                'firstId': "=",
                'secondId': "="
            },
            templateUrl: 'Views/layout/some.info.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $attrs) {
                someService.getSome($scope.firstId).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.some= response.data.some;
                }, function (error) { });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Usage:

```
<some-info firstId='myFirst' secondId='mySecond'></some-info>
```

Also, how do I enforce passing the two params.

Comment: can you share your controller code, where you must be setting these params...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

camelCase is converted to dashes in parameters:

```
<some-info first-id="myFirst" second-id="mySecond"></some-info>
```